# how to click <a> in a webpage without class name or id or with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

how to click a button in a webpage without class name or id,
this is the web code

```
<a href="https://example.com" style="text-decoration:none;line-height:100%;background:#5865f2;color:white;font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:15px;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;margin:0px;" target="_blank">
            Verify Email
          </a>
```

I tried this code

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/a').click()
```

but it show this in the log

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

and I tried this too

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Verify Email').click()
```

and it show this in the log

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

and I tried to add `time.sleep(5)` before it but the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like there are **spaces**, so can you try with **partial_link_text** as well :-

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Verify Email').click()
```

or with the below xpath :

```
//a[@href='https://example.com']
```

or

```
//a[contains(@href,'https://example.com')]
```

or

```
//a[contains(text(),'Verify Email')]
```

**Update 1 :**

There is an iframe involved, so driver focus needs to be switch to iframe first and then we can click on `Verify Email`, see below :-

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.gmailnator.com/sizetmp/messageid/#17b0678c05a9616e")
driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "message-body")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Verify Email')]"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"Verify Email"}
(the link keep changing every time so i have to locate the button

Comment: is there any iframe ? can you check for that ? can you share page url ?

Comment: https://www.gmailnator.com/sizetmp/messageid/#17b0678c05a9616e

Comment: okay that is cause we have an iframe `message-body` in place, so we need to switch over to click on verify email. See the above updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath locator:

```py
//a[contains(text(),'Verify Email')]
```

Or this:

```py
//a[@href='https://example.com']
```

So your code will be

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Verify Email')]").click()
```

or

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='https://example.com']").click()
```

Also possibly you have to add a wait to let the element loaded.
In this case your code will be:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Verify Email')]"))).click()
```

or

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='https://example.com']"))).click()
```